# how to give full AWS account access to a user that belong to a group

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

How can I give a user that belong to a group full access to the AWS Console?

I have created a user `JohnDoe` from the AWS Console, then a group called `Admin`. Then I attached a policy called `administrator access` which has the follow in Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But unfortunately, after I log in as `JohnDoe` and try to look for AWS Billing, I receive the message below.

[image]

If i understand correctly, the process below is the correct one to give full access to the AWS to `JohnDoe`?

I look forward to receive some help and know what i am doing wrong, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the user has all the necessary rights and permissions, in order for an IAM user to be able to see the billing console, we have to active the `IAM User Access to Billing Information` as it is described in the following AWS blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/dont-forget-to-enable-access-to-the-billing-console/

We have to sign in with the root account, go to the [account settings](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/account) and activate IAM access:

[image]